# tmpfs and debian - trash folder

Tags: memory, debian, gui, tmpfs

I have created a tmpfs that remounts on boot and works as I had hoped for. My ram folder is here...

```
/home/user/ramdrive/
```

While testing I noticed that when I delete files via the Debian GUI the files get sent to

```
/home/user/ramdrive/.Trash-1001/
```

When deleting files from the ramdrive via the command line it's gone for good which is what I want, but I would like this to happen in the GUI too.

Can someone explain why files deleted via the GUI send files here instead of to the trash.

Does my fstab command that remounts the drive need to specify something extra?

---

Sorry I think I might not have explained the issue too well...

Deleting anything within the ramdrive (/home/user/ramdrive/*), which is mounted, ends up in /home/user/ramdrive/.Trash-1001/.

After some digging around this morning I think that's normal behaviour when you delete something that is on a mounted drive...it goes into a dir/.Trash folder, where dir is the root of the mounted volume.

I was hoping there would be a way around this...the best thing I have found is being able to right click and selecting "delete".

To get this extra option....

System > Preferences > File Management > Behaviour > Check "Include a delete command that bypasses the wastebasket"

I'm still learning the Debian environment so there may be a better way of doing this.

Comment: Don't you think it's easier to wipe the trash folder on logout? Consider what would happen to your ram disk when you delete a 50 GiB file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIR, trash directories are created on per volume basis.

However, most GUI file managers support `Shift+Del` key shortcut for deleting files permanently, bypassing trash.

`rm` command is not trash-aware (and it shouldn't be).